# Convergence towards the Tracy-Widom distribution

Tags: pr.probability

If $X_n$ is an $n \times n$ GUE random matrix with largest eigenvalue $\lambda_n$, then
$n^{1/6} (\lambda_n - \sqrt {2n})$ converges in distribution towards the Tracy-Widom law. Could this convergence also hold in total variation?

Comment: If I remember correctly the error in the Tracy-Widom distribution is of order $n^{-2/3}e^{-|\lambda-\sqrt{2n}|}$, so the integral over $\lambda$ (the total variation) indeed goes to zero when $n\rightarrow\infty $